# Sound Driver says speakers unplugged on Dell Inspiron N4010 running Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, dell-inspiron

My sound icon says that my internal speakers are not plugged in. When I remove and reinstall the drivers the sound works fine. But the same problem occurs again after a reboot.

I am using Windows 7 Home Basic on a Dell Inspiron N4010.

Comment: Are you using Windows' default drivers, or the manufacturer's drivers? Sometimes one will work while the other is flaky.

Comment: i am using manufacturer's driver.

Comment: Is it the current one? Dell evidently released an updated version after shipping the first one. Try this one: http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails/Product/inspiron-14r?driverId=WWPR3&osCode=W764&fileId=2731096851

Comment: @KA: yes I have used the same driver as per your link (I have no idea what is happening after reboot) and thanks people for editing and making this question more intuitive.